# Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Model of Task =>

```
class Task {


Task({this.isDone,this.name,this.time,this.priorityValue});
  final String name;
   bool isDone;
   final DateTime time;
   int priorityValue;



 factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
    return Task(
      name: jsonData['name'],
      isDone: false,
      time: jsonData['time'],
      priorityValue: jsonData['priorityValue'],
    );
  }

  toJSONEncodable() {
    Map<String, dynamic> m = new Map();

    m['name'] = name;
    m['isDone'] = isDone;
    m['time'] = time;
    m['priorityValue'] = priorityValue;

    return m;
  }

  static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(Task task) => {
        'name': task.name,
        'isDone': task.isDone,
        'time': task.time,
        'priorityValue': task.priorityValue,
      };
}
```

and When using the localStorage package to save some list of objects I got this error =>

(Flutter) Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime'

```
_saveToStorage() {
storage.setItem('tasks', list.toJSONEncodable());
print("Saved");
```

}

i tried to use .toString() but then i get this error => type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

any Idea to save Datetime on LocalStorage package?

**Update:**

```
factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonData) {
return Task(
  name: jsonData['name'],
  isDone: false,
  time: jsonData["time"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(jsonData["time"]),
  priorityValue: jsonData['priorityValue'],
);


 }

  toJSONEncodable() {
Map<String, dynamic> m = new Map();

m['name'] = name;
m['isDone'] = isDone;
m['time'] = time == null ? null : time.toIso8601String();
m['priorityValue'] = priorityValue;

return m;


 }

static Map<String, dynamic> toMap(Task task) => {
    'name': task.name,
    'isDone': task.isDone,
    'time': task.time,
    'priorityValue': task.priorityValue,
  };


var items = storage.getItem('tasks');
            if (items != null) {
              list.items = List<Task>.from(
                (items as List).map(
                  (item) => Task(
                    name: item['name'],
                    isDone: item['isDone'],
                    time: DateTime.parse(item['time']),
                    priorityValue: items['priorityValue'],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
```

After the update i got this error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'"

**Update2:**

```
var items = storage.getItem('tasks');

            if (items != null) {
              final decodedJson = jsonDecode(items);
              list.items = (decodedJson as List)
                  .map((e) => Task.fromJson(e))
                  .toList();
              final task = list.items.first;
              print("${task.name}");
              // list.items = List<Task>.from(
              //   (items as List).map(
              //     (item) => Task(
              //       name: item['name'],
              //       isDone: item['isDone'],
              //       time: DateTime.parse(item['time']),
              //       priorityValue: items['priorityValue'],
              //     ),
              //   ),
              // );
            }
```

After the second update i got "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

**Fixed**

I changed the DateTime to a String in the model and convert the time to a string when got it by

```
"${selectedDate.toLocal()}".split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 17):

use toJson

`"changeDate": changeDate == null ? null : changeDate.toIso8601String(),`

and fromJson

`changeDate: json["changeDate"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["changeDate"]),`

Comment: i did in the from JSON DateTime.parse(jsonData['time'])
 and in to JSON m['time'] = time.toIso8601String();

and now i get this error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Comment: i added one morre code 
var items = storage.getItem('tasks');
                if (items != null) {
                  list.items = List<Task>.from(
                    (items as List).map(
                      (item) => Task(
                        name: item['name'],
                        isDone: item['isDone'],
                        time: DateTime.parse(item['time']),
                        priorityValue: items['priorityValue'],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
     }
now getting type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Comment: 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' looks like an issue with fromJson, but your snippet looks fine. Maybe you can put an update of your code to your question. type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'  means you are mistakenly using a map index for a list -> so `myVar['time']` instead of `myVar[1]`

Comment: The **toJson** code above can be further simplified with: `"changeDate": changeDate?.toIso8601String(),`. See [prefer_null_aware_operators](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_null_aware_operators.html)

Answer (score -1):

I'd highly recommend you to use [Retrofit](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit) and [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) for describing your API

It could look like so:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'task.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(nullable: false, explicitToJson: true)
class Task {
  final String name;
  bool isDone;
  final DateTime time;
  int priorityValue;

  Task({this.isDone, this.name, this.time, this.priorityValue});

  factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TaskFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TaskToJson(this);
}
```

after that you need to run `build_runner`: 
`flutter pub run build_runner build`

and it will generate you both `toJson` and `fromJson` methods without any pain:

```dart
Task _$TaskFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Task(
    isDone: json['isDone'] as bool,
    name: json['name'] as String,
    time: DateTime.parse(json['time'] as String),
    priorityValue: json['priorityValue'] as int,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$TaskToJson(Task instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'name': instance.name,
      'isDone': instance.isDone,
      'time': instance.time.toIso8601String(),
      'priorityValue': instance.priorityValue,
    };
```

You can check out the test:

```dart
void main() {
  test('Task should be parsed from json', () {
    const json = '''
    [
      {
        "name": "testing",
        "isDone": false,
        "time": "2021-01-12T13:57:10.705476",
        "priorityValue": 0
      }
    ]
    ''';

    final List decodedJson = jsonDecode(json);
    final List<Task> list = decodedJson.map((e) => Task.fromJson(e)).toList();

    final Task task = list.first;

    expect(task.name, 'testing');
    expect(task.isDone, false);
    expect(task.time, DateTime.parse("2021-01-12T13:57:10.705476"));
    expect(task.priorityValue, 0);
  });
}
```

Comment: var items = storage.getItem('tasks');
print("$items");

I/flutter ( 8537): [{name: testing, isDone: false, time: 2021-01-12T13:57:10.705476, priorityValue: 0}]

Comment: the time var of type String so i added time: DateTime.parse(item['time']),

type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' will appear

Comment: Double check what you try to pass to `fromJson` method, also check out what are the types